# SimpleXmlElement throws exception, after having worked fine for over a year

Tags: php, rss, simplexml

A few years ago I made a simple RSS to SSS converter (so I could get my RSS feed into a format that Second Life's LSL could handle).
It's been working fine for over a year, until a few days ago (1 May to be exact). Since then, it's been throwing an **error**.

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could
>   not be parsed as XML' in /home/[username
>   hidden]/public_html/API/rss2sss.php:4
>   Stack trace: #0 /home/[username
>   hidden]/public_html/API/rss2sss.php(4):
>   SimpleXMLElement->__construct('') #1 {main} thrown in /home/[username
>   hidden]/public_html/API/rss2sss.php on line 4

The code in **rss2sss.php**:

```
﻿<?php
$feedUrl = $_GET['rss'];
$rawFeed = file_get_contents($feedUrl);
$xml = new SimpleXmlElement($rawFeed); /*This is where the exception happens*/


$channel['title'] = $xml->channel->title;
$channel['link']  = $xml->channel->link;

echo '<sss>';

foreach ($xml->channel->item as $item)
{    

    $article = array();
    $article['title'] = $item->title;
    $article['link'] = $item->link;

    echo '
    <pre>
        <title>';
    echo $article['title'] .'</title>
        <link>';
    echo $article['link'];
    echo '</link>
    </pre>';
}

echo '
</sss>';
?>
```

The RSS I'm trying to convert has not changed format in years, and is taken from [this feed](http://www.thetorchentertainmentguide.com/feed/).

Any help at all in finding out why the code suddenly broke would be greatly appreciated, as it is affecting the visit rate of the site quite significantly.

Comment: Can you post `$rawFeed` value this may be not well formatted `xml`.

Comment: @ARIFMAHMUDRANA It seems like rawFeed turns up empty, so no, I would not call that well formatted.
I can't figure out why though, because feedURL turns up correctly.

Comment: Can you post the feed url?

Comment: @ARIFMAHMUDRANA I posted it in the original post. It's http://www.thetorchentertainmentguide.com/feed/

Comment: Strange. When I edited the code to echo the rawFeed string and then edited that out again (only adding and then removing the echo line, no other changes), the converter worked again... once.
When I refreshed the page, it showed the SSS correctly, refreshed again and the error is back.

I got no clue what's going on!

Comment: It would seem there's something wrong with the feed from the URL I'm pulling it from. Though I haven't changed anything about the feed, I tried pulling a feed from another site and that worked just fine.

Still don't know what's wrong though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still not sure what happened or where things got wrong, but the fault was not with the PHP, but with the RSS feed I was trying to pull.

After a lot of cache purging and fiddling with the settings (nothing with formatting, only how many items should be visible in the feed), it suddenly started working as intended again. I deduced that it was the plugin W3Cache for Wordpress that caused the problem. Don't know why it started now, after having worked for so long, but disabling that plugin (after purging all caches one last time (important step)) fixed that problem.

Still, don't know what exactly was wrong with the formatting of the XML, did a text compare between both the old feed and the new, working one and the only differences are the time codes from latest update, nothing in the formatting.